# In the TV Series VEEP, why is a spy in the hostage situation a negative thing?

Tags: plot-explanation, veep

I just started watching VEEP and I was in Season 2, Episode 5 where it was revealed that one of the hostages in Uzbekistan was a spy and it is implied that:

1. This is somehow bad (as I understand it)
2. Or maybe it is implied that the President lying about the spy was
   bad. (I'm guessing this is the actual reason the media is mad)

I don't know which one, so could someone explain that?

If it is #1, then why is it bad to have a spy working for their own government (in the last part of the episode, the Finnish media is asking the VEEP about the CIA spy) as one of the hostages? Doesn't that make intelligence gathering and debriefing easy?

If it is #2, what could the President have done, other than lie? I mean, he can't openly admit on national media that there's a spy in the group of hostages right? The captors would've killed them all immediately.

Either this or I may have missed something. Could someone please elaborate?

Comment: I don't watch the show, so I can't even speculate with out context and/or without knowing if this was a random plot or ongoing, but I do know that US-Uzbekistan relations is vital to the US's goal in stabilizing the Middle East, but I don't understand how Finland knowing/exposing this would be threatening or what Finland would gain by exposing something that might be considered unsavory/illegal in some way. Here's wiki page on US-Uzbek. relations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States%E2%80%93Uzbekistan_relations

Comment: How sure are you that the bad thing is "a spy in a hostage situation", as opposed to "shit, one of our spies is in danger. If he's killed, we lose a valuable asset"? Because the latter is very easily explainable, and your question doesn't exclude the possibility.

Comment: I am very sure, because the President tells the media there are no spies among the hostages at first, but then the media finds out anyway and they accuse the president of lying, for which he ALMOST gets impeached! He later resigns anyway.